# Coordinating conjunction at beginning of sentence

Tags: sentence, conjunctions

Reading Wallace Shawn’s new book NIGHT THOUGHTS and he uses this construction all the time.

And I knew my childhood memories affected it.
But that theory wouldn’t work.

How do you show that first conjunction in a sentence diagram?

Comment: The category label would be 'coordinator', and the function label 'marker'. The remainder of the clause would be labelled as normal, i.e. subject-predicate.